# Why is key (or value) of Map<String, String> not returned as String?

Tags: java, dictionary

In the following short code snippet, Eclipse flags an error about the `String key = pair.getKey();` and the `String value = pair.getValue();` statements, saying that

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from
>   Object to String"

This is the relevant code:

```
    for (Map<String, String> dic : dics) {
        Iterator it = dic.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            String key = pair.getKey();
            String value = pair.getValue();
        }               
    }
```

Why is that?

All examples I have seen so far, do not cast pair.getKey() or pair.getValue() to String, so I would like to understand what's happening before proceeding with a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (Map<String, String> dic : dics) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = dic.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
        String key = pair.getKey();
        String value = pair.getValue();
    }               
}
```

Or even better (internal working is identical, but this is less verbose):

```
for (Map<String, String> dic : dics) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dic.entrySet()){
        String key = pair.getKey();
        String value = pair.getValue();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have not carried the types through the `it` or `pair`

Try this

```
for (Map<String, String> dic : dics) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dic.entrySet()) {
        String key = pair.getKey();
        String value = pair.getValue();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (Map<String, String> dic : dics) {
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = dic.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
      String key = pair.getKey();
      String value = pair.getValue();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea is that your **iterator(it)** and **entry(pair)**  should also be generics-ized.

```
                Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = dic.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
                    String key = pair.getKey();
                    String value = pair.getValue();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Entry` as a raw unparametrized type type.

Use `Entry<String, String>` instead of the raw `Entry`.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of Map.Entry is not parameterized by type.